# How do I setup a vue template on laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am scratching my head since serveral days about how to adapt this template: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vuetify-material-dashboard#
to a laravel install.
So far what I have done:
1./ fresh install of laravel, tested it works with php artisan serve and set up a vue frontend following this tutorial : https://laravel-news.com/building-vue-spa-laravel-part-2/
2./ download the template folder, run npm serve and tested it work separately
3./ took the the full src folder of the material design copied paste it in ressources/js and took all the laravel files which were inside the ressources/js and issue from the tutorial and placed it an /old folder I then renamed the main.js from the template into app.js

But still I see the result of the tutorial.
What do I miss  or what would be the procedure according to you to set up this template in Laravel 7 ?